# Using srcsets in a custom block

Tags: images, block-editor

I'm building a few custom blocks and have come across something I am not sure is either possible at the current time (as there does not seem to be docs on it), or it is something people are still figuring out.

I'm wondering is it possible to access the image srcsets in a custom blocks. This is my current markup which is accessing the sizes array to get my chosen image size. Which is ok, but obviously not ideal when you get down to a mobile size.

```js
attributes: {
            mediaID: {
                type: "number",
            },
            mediaURL: {
                type: "string",
                source: "attribute",
                selector: "img.promogroupitem__media--img",
                attribute: "src",
            },
            mediaAlt: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'attribute',
                selector: 'img.promogroupitem__media--img',
                attribute: 'alt'
            },
            mediaWidth: {
                type: 'number',
                source: 'attribute',
                selector: 'img.promogroupitem__media--img',
                attribute: 'width',
            },
            mediaHeight: {
                type: 'number',
                source: 'attribute',
                selector: 'img.promogroupitem__media--img',
                attribute: 'height',
            },  
        },
        parent: 'wpboiler-core/promo-group',

        edit: function(props) {
            const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
            const { 
                mediaID,
                mediaURL,
                mediaAlt,
                mediaWidth,
                mediaHeight, 
            } = attributes;

            const onSelectImage = media => setAttributes({ 
                mediaID: media.id, 
                mediaURL: (media.sizes.promo ? media.sizes.promo.url : media.url),
                mediaAlt: media.alt,
                mediaWidth: (media.sizes.promo ? media.sizes.promo.width : media.width),
                mediaHeight: (media.sizes.promo ? media.sizes.promo.height : media.height),
            });

            return el(
                'article',
                useBlockProps(attributes),

                el(
                    InspectorControls, 
                    null,

                    // IMAGE UPLOAD BEGIN
                    el(
                        PanelBody,
                        {
                          title: "Background Image",
                        },
            
                        el(MediaUpload, {
                          onSelect: onSelectImage,
                          allowedTypes: "image",
                          value: mediaID,
                          render: (obj) => {
                            return el(
                              Button,
                              {
                                className: "components-button is-primary",
                                onClick: obj.open,
                              },
                              !mediaID
                                ? __("Upload Image", "card-group")
                                : __("Replace Image", "card-group")
                            );
                          },
                        }),
            
                        mediaID
                          ? el(
                              Button,
                              {
                                className: "components-button is-tertiary",
                                style: { marginLeft: "5px" },
                                onClick: () => setAttributes({ 
                                    mediaID: "", 
                                    mediaURL: "",
                                    mediaAlt: "",
                                    mediaHeight: "",
                                    mediaWidth: "",
                                }),
                              },
                              "Remove Image"
                            )
                          : ""
                      )
                      // IMAGE UPLOAD END

                ),
                
                el(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'promogroupitem__container' },

                    mediaURL ? 
                    el(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'promogroupitem__media' },

                        el(
                            'img',
                            { 
                                className: 'promogroupitem__media--img',
                                src: mediaURL,
                                loading: 'lazy',
                                width: mediaWidth,
                                height: mediaHeight,
                                alt: mediaAlt,
                            }
                        ),
                    ) : '',
                )
            );
        },

save: function(props) {
            const { attributes } = props;
            const { 
                mediaURL, 
                mediaAlt,
                mediaHeight,
                mediaWidth, 
            } = attributes;

            return el(
                'article',
                { className: 'promogroupitem' },

                el(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'promogroupitem__container' },

                    mediaURL ?
                    el(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'promogroupitem__media' },

                        el(
                            'img', { 
                                className: 'promogroupitem__media--img',
                                src: mediaURL,
                                loading: 'lazy',
                                width: mediaWidth,
                                height: mediaHeight,
                                alt: mediaAlt,
                            }
                        ),
                    ) : '',

                ),
            );
        },
```

Its something I am not quite sure how to resolve. Has anyone come across this and developed/found a solution for it?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the srcsets for the core image blocks are not added by the block in the editor, they're added on output by the [`wp_filter_content_tags`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filter_content_tags/) function, which is a filter on `the_content`.

Comment: I may have confused things by only including my edit function, I've updated to include the save function also. If they are generated via `the_content()` filter does that mean `parse_blocks()` can be utilised to generate the srcsets on the frontend?

Comment: `parse_blocks()` doesn't have anything to do with it. It just means that when the content is output on the front end, the `srcset` attributes should be added to any `<img>` tags automatically, as long as the image is from the media library. The bit I left out is that the image needs a class like`wp-image-51`, but with the correct image ID instead of `51`.

Comment: Bloody hell, as easy as that. Thanks